# Multi level Caesar Cipher encryption

Tags: python

So I am working on Problem Set 4 for MIT Open Courseware. I tried referencing their solution, but it isn't there for some reason. They posted the wrong answers. So, here's my problem.

The description of what it's supposed to do is this: "This function takes a string text and a list of tuples shifts. The tuples in shifts represent the location of the shift, and the shift itself. For example a tuple of (0,2) means that the shift starts are position 0 in the string and is a Caesar shift of 2. Additionally, the shifts are layered. This means that a set of shifts [(0,2), (5, 3)] will first apply a Caesar shift of 2 to the entire string, and then apply a Caesar shift of 3 starting at the 6th letter in the string"

so this is what I wrote:

```
def apply_shifts(text, shifts):
    encryptedText = text
    for t in shifts:
        encryptedText = apply_shift(encryptedText[t[0]:len(encryptedText)], t[1])
        print encryptedText
    return encryptedText
```

So, I know that I'm telling it to replace the variable I'm referencing every time it iterates thorough the loop. I just don't know how to set it up so I don't have that issue. here is my test:

```
print apply_shifts("Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?", [(0,6), (3, 18), (12, 16)])
print 'JufYkaolfapxQdrnzmasmRyrpfdvpmEurrb?'
```

The first print statement is my test, and the second is what the output should be. Any ideas?

Comment: The apply_shift function takes (text, shift) as the argument. It uses another piece of code I wrote to perform the actual shift. There isn't a problem with it.

Comment: Mmmh... Maybe I'm missing something, but I cannot see where did you describe your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend the result of apply_shift with the non-shifted part on each iteration :

- the + operator concatenates strings
- You can use the slice short syntax to get a slice of the string from the beginning s[:i], or to the end s[i:]

  encryptedText = encryptedText[:t[0]] + apply_shift(encryptedText[t[0]:], t[1])

Comment: That makes sense. I don't have time today, but tomorrow I will put that together and see if it works how I want it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few functions I might recommend a recursive function to do!

```
import string

def apply_shift(text,shift):
    ciphertext = string.ascii_uppercase+string.ascii_lowercase
    cipherdict = {char:idx for idx,char in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase+string.ascii_lowercase)}
    loop_amt = len(ciphertext)

    start,shift = shift
    text = list(text)
    for idx,char in enumerate(text[start:]):
        idx = start+idx
        if char not in cipherdict: continue
        else: text[idx] = ciphertext[(cipherdict[char]+shift)%loop_amt]
    return ''.join(text)

def apply_shifts(text,shifts):
    start,shift = shifts.pop(-1)
    if shifts:
        return apply_shifts(apply_shift(text,(start,shift)),shifts)
    else:
        return apply_shift(text,(start,shift))
```

Comment: I had thought of trying a recursive method, but I couldn't figure out how to implement it. Thanks!